# Magento 2 Cannot create shipment Rest Api

Tags: magento2, rest-api, shipment

I am trying to create shipment after refund in magento through Rest Api but it is giving error "Cannot create shipment without item". My shipment was of 5 quantity out of which I have refunded 2 item and trying to create another shipment of 3 quantity but then it is giving error. Where I am wrong or Magento allow this or not?

Comment: Please provide your request json , it is better if you can put also the Order body (json)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to include the items in the shipment JSON for the API in order to ship the whole order.  See my answer here: [How do I create a shipment via REST API?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109844/how-do-i-create-a-shipment-via-rest-api)