# Magento 2 REST API Shipping "Can't create a shipment without products."

Tags: magento2, shipping, rest-api

a bit lost, I'm attempting to use

{SiteUrl}/rest/V1/order/{id}/ship

using litterally the request found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109844/how-do-i-create-a-shipment-via-rest-api):

```
{
  "tracks": [
    {
      "track_number": "1Y-9876543210",
      "title": "Custom",
      "carrier_code": "SomeCarrierCode"
    }
  ]
}
```

The answer at the bottom, and several others I have seen imply that this should be sufficient to create a shipment via the url provided, and funnily enough while postman doesn't save the responses like the Talend plugin does, I was certain I was using this code via postman to correctly submit to two different Magento sites.

Today i finally worked out an issue with my code that was stopping me from posting these, and curiously even going back into postman i am now getting the following response

```
{
    "message": "Shipment Document Validation Error(s):\nThe order does not allow a shipment to be created.\nYou can't create a shipment without products."
}
```

I have tried on both a completed order (one that previously worked) and 2 new orders with completed invoices.

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong? (I am confident I have the Oauth Correct because getOrders is working.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.3-admin/tag/orderorderIdship#operation/salesShipOrderV1ExecutePost

Full payload example:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "extension_attributes": { },
            "order_item_id": 0,
            "qty": 0
        }
    ],
    "notify": true,
    "appendComment": true,
    "comment": {
        "extension_attributes": { },
        "comment": "string",
        "is_visible_on_front": 0
    },
    "tracks": [
        {
            "extension_attributes": { },
            "track_number": "string",
            "title": "string",
            "carrier_code": "string"
        }
    ],
    "packages": [
        {
            "extension_attributes": { }
        }
    ],
    "arguments": {
        "extension_attributes": {
            "source_code": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

... where as per the docs

```
comment/comment
comment/is_visible_on_frontend
items[]/order_item_id
items[]/qty
tracks[]/carrier_code
tracks[]/title
tracks[]/track_number
```

are required.

Comment: Thanks, i was really hoping this wasn't the case, as it was.. somehow previously working, without the need to pull the order item ID, which.. I don't seem to have. the only reference to this via the API i can find is the invoice and we aren't generating that to store that ID.

Comment: I think you're not wrong - just checked an old implementation of the shipping api of mine, there I didn't specify the items to ship either. Can you check in `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Validation\QuantityValidator` from where the error response is actually returned (the mentioned string is used twice in there)?

Comment: baffled.. just created a new order and posted, it works.. admittedly when i went looking at the order to again, try to find these order_item_id's i noted that the order i was posting thought the single item in it, had been despatched... so i tried creating a new order.. maybe this is a problem in testing with my codebase or setup.. ill try a few more this evening, if it works ill mark your answer correct and add my own below stating my findings (i think that way what 99% of people are getting wrong will be the right answer and anyone  with this edge case will be covered).. many thanks

Comment: Nothing wrong with accepting your own answer as correct if it is applicable to the particular problem you were facing ;)